# Visual Studio Solution Files

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I seem to continually have a problem when merging VS solution files, in that two sections of the file, somehow, become out of sync.  The two sections are here:

```
Global
 GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
      SccNumberOfProjects = 60
      SccEnterpriseProvider = {1CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184D}
      SccTeamFoundationServer = https://tfs.com
      SccLocalPath0 = .
      SccProjectUniqueName1 = Project\\Path\\Project.vbproj
...
```

And here:

```
 GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
      SccNumberOfProjects = 60
      SccEnterpriseProvider = {1CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184D}
      SccTeamFoundationServer = https://tfs.com
      SccLocalPath0 = .
      SccProjectUniqueName1 = Project\\Path\\Project.vbproj
```

These are two distinct areas of the solution file, but they seem to become out of sync quite frequently.  I realise this is caused because the merge wasn't done correctly, but merging solution files is difficult.  So, my question is this:  Why are there two separate sections of this file that, as far as I can see, are mirrors of each other?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the source control related section jump around in solution files, causing merge conflicts.

Not sure why the section is moved around, but if that happens and a merge is not resolved correctly, it could result in duplication.

You can probably see where the duplicates came from in your source control log (blame).

Most likely you can safely remove the duplicate.